# How to compare and paste the row by xlwings

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlwings

I have a two sheet
the following is sheet A:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqVuv.png)

And here is sheet B:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/warYN.png)

If the data (AVLevel+Description) in sheet B but not in sheet A:
insert this data in sheet A (location depends on the last data)

If the data in sheet A but not in sheet B:
give strikethrough in sheet A

cause I want to keep the excel format,so I want to use the xlwings to finish this issue.
How can I do!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this example.
The criteria checks are probably not exhaustive and may be you might be wanting to copy more than just a cell to the other sheet.
This example also expects the two sheets to be in the same workbook.

```
import xlwings as xw


excelfile = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excelfile)

    ### Headers for columns to be checked
    search_headers = ['Description', 'AV\\nLevel\n2']

    ### Get highest last used row in Sheets A and B
    last_row_list = []
    sheet_names_list = [sht.name for sht in wb.sheets]

    for sht in sheet_names_list:
            last_row_list.append(wb.sheets(f'{sht}').
                             range(f'D{wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row}').end('up').row)

    ### Last used row on either sheet
    mr = max(last_row_list)

    ### Get last Column
    # last_c_num = wb.sheets(sheet_names_list[0])["A1"].expand("right").last_cell.column
    last_c_let = wb.sheets(sheet_names_list[0])["A1"].expand("right").last_cell.address.split("$")[1]

    ### List of Headers in row 1
    hlist = wb.sheets(1).range(f"A1:{last_c_let}{mr}").options(ndim=2).value[0]

    ### Obtain the columns with the Headers 'Description', 'AV\\nLevel\n2'
    head_col = []
    for header in wb.sheets(1).range(f"A1:{last_c_let}{mr}").options(ndim=2).value[0]:
        if header in search_headers:
            r = [x for x in range(len(hlist)) if hlist[x] == header][0]+1
            head_col.append(r)

    ### Loop through the columns 'Description', 'AV\\nLevel\n2'
    for sht_a_cell in wb.sheets(sheet_names_list[0]).range((1, head_col[0]), (mr, head_col[1])):
        ### Skipping header row
        if sht_a_cell.row == 1:
            continue

        ### Corresponding sht_a_cell in SheetB
        sht_b_cell = wb.sheets(sheet_names_list[1]).cells(sht_a_cell.row, sht_a_cell.column)

        ### Values for SheetA and its corresponding sht_a_cell in SheetB
        print(f"Cell Address: {sht_a_cell.address} {sheet_names_list[0]} value: '{sht_a_cell.value}'")
        print(f"Cell Address: {sht_b_cell.address} {sheet_names_list[1]} value: '{sht_b_cell.value}")

        ### Compare the SheetA value with Sheet B value
        ### and run operations based on the cell values
        if sht_a_cell.value != sht_b_cell.value:
            print('Cell values are different!')
            ### If SheetA value is none invoke Requirement 1
            if sht_a_cell.value is None:
                print(f"{sheet_names_list[0]} c_value is empty, does not match {sheet_names_list[1]} value!")
                print(f"Copy {sheet_names_list[1]} value to {sheet_names_list[0]}.")
                sht_b_cell.copy(sht_a_cell)
            ### If SheetA has values not on SheetB invoke Requirement 2
            elif sht_b_cell.value is None:
                print(f"{sheet_names_list[1]} does not contain the value in {sheet_names_list[0]}")
                print(f"Setting {sheet_names_list[0]} font to strikethrough.")
                sht_a_cell.font.impl.xl.Strikethrough = True

        else:
            print('Cell values are the same!')


        print('')
    wb.save("out_foo.xlsx")
```